# ¿Cómo volver (hacia atrás) exactamente a la pantalla anterior? y ¿Cómo volver (hacia adelante) exactamente de donde regresamos?

Tags: java, android

Por ejemplo. tengo una aplicación que construyo yo mismo. El cual constra de ***3 activities*** en los 3 manejo datos es decir los 3 activities tienen los ***editText con valores***. La primera llama a la segunda y la segunda llama a la tercera activity. Tambien de la segunda se puede volver a la primera así como desde la tercera se puede volver a la segunda.

Mi problema radica en que yo solo uso 2 opciones hasta el momento y son:

**Opcion 1:** `finish();`

**Opcion 2:** `Intent myIntent = new Intent(nombreClase.this,activityDestiny.class);`

Al usar por ejemplo la opcion 1: sería:

Desde la 1era activity llamo con un intent a la siguiente activity perfecto ok. Luego desde la segunda para volver uso FINISH() si me regresa exactamente a la pantalla anterior osea al primero, luego nuevamente quiero ir al segundo activity entonces al usar nuevamente un intent éste lo que haría es ir a una nueva ventana vacía, aparte de que con el finish elimine para siempre de la memoria, ENTONCES NO ME SIRVEN.

Al usar la opcion 2: el uso de intent

Desde la 1era activity uso `intent` para llamar a la 2da luego desde la segunda llamo a la primera activity con un `intent` pero este no me regresa a la primera sino que me crea como una copia igual a la primera activity que tiene datos, ésta ultima copia viene vacía sin datos.

De ahí que yo quiero navegar exactamente en los activities que voy creando para mantener mis datos. ¿Cómo haría eso? Ayudenme por favor, no fue facil escribir todo este texto. Gracias. Me imagino que tengo que aprender usar el onResume y el onPause() pero no se como hacerlo en este momento.

Comment: No seria mejor trabajar con fragment? podrias tener solo una actividad y tres fragment, como la app de whatsapp ...

Comment: Puedes por favor pegar aqui tu código de tu primera y segunda actividad, acabo de hacer la prueba yo mismo y me funciona. A lo mejor es que no te he entendido correctamente, yo he hecho un intent que me lleve de la actividad 1 a la actividad 2 mediante un boton "ir", luego presionando un boton "volver" en la actividad 2 llamo a finish() y me devuelve a la actividad1, despues uso de nuevo el boton "ir" de la actividad 1 para viajar de nuevo a la actividad 2 y funciona correctamente.

Comment: si me regresa a la activiy 2, pero ésa activity es una copia de la segunda no es la misma que abriste anteriormente. ¿Por que cada que se ejecute Intent miIntent = new Intent(...); creará otro clon del primero que creastes

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar la función `onBackPressed();`

Esta función es la misma que se presenta en las `Toolbar` con la *"fecha atrás"*

1- `finish()` : Destruye una actividad y no podrás acceder a ella hasta que la vuelvas a crear.

2- `onBackPressed()` : Vuelve a la `activity` o `fragment` anterior al que te encuentras en el momento, todo depende de como lo hayas programado.

La primera función en resumen destruye tu actividad la segunda la cierra.

Puedes añadir una funcionalidad extra usando (Aquí creo que podrías darle uso a lo que tu deseas)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
...
}
```

Comment: Esto no es correcto, por defecto onBackPressed() llama a finish() si no se sobreescribe.

Comment: Una cierra y la otra puede usar finish para cerrar, si no no tendría sentido tener dos ... @Reductor

Comment: Gracias a sus comentarios los he utilizado de alguna  manera. pero no logre mís objetivos sin embargo lo que estoy haciendo es obligar a que haga lo  que quiero. Nuevamente les agradezco a todos por su ayuda. Lo que hice fue crear variables en memoria de android studio e hice que cuando me abriera nuevamente el activity los valores que copié, nuevamente los asigne. Sin embargo no me parece correcto, pero no me queda de otra a ver si me indican que les parece ésto. gracias.

Comment: De que se trata tu proyecto ? @RiouriSatsumoto

Comment: Hola, se trata de registro de Facturas, y consiste en tener campos EditText en los cuales se seleccionan o ingresan datos para almacenarlos en un BD. y lo que que se quiere es que cada vez que se va a otra pantalla o incluso cuando se pone en onPause o en onStop al volver a las ventanas se visualizen los datos ingresados anteriormente, porque con android studio si vuelves a la pantalla(segun mi conocimiento) los datos ingresados se pierden

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es pasar los datos de la actividad una a la dos y así evitas volver. Validas que los datos ingresados sean correctos y sigues

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es que revises como funciona realmente un activity porque veo que quieres regresar a otra activity que previamente destruiste. La activity solo existe mientras este dormida y siempre la puedes llamar nuevamente. Una vez que la destruyes la tienes que instanciar nuevamente. En cuanto a los parametros, existe formas de enviarlos entre activities.
Revisa este link

[Estructura Activity Android](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm)

Comment: gracias _______